# What is Closure in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, closures

I saw one Laravel function in middlewere:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check())
    {
       return redirect('/home');
    } 

    return $next($request);
}
```

What is `Closure` and what does it do?

Comment: Closure is a function contained by variable here `$next` . And `Closure` before param `$next` is type hinting. Ask your next question ?

Comment: i dont get it. can you please explain in breif ?

Comment: You need to check this before  : http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: ok, i dont have any choice now..

Comment: OK!! , that link is useful for me..Thanks for your effort !!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

A [Closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) is an anonymous function. Closures are often used as callback methods and can be used as a parameter in a function.

If you take the following example:

```
function handle(Closure $closure) {
    $closure();
}

handle(function(){
    echo 'Hello!';
});
```

We start by adding a `Closure` parameter the `handle` function. This will type hint us that the `handle` function takes a `Closure`.

We then call the `handle` function and pass a function as the first parameter.

By using `$closure();` in the `handle` function we tell PHP to execute the given `Closure` which will then `echo 'Hello!'`

It is also possible to pass parameters into a `Closure`. We can do so by changing the `Closure` call in the `handle` function to pass on a parameter. In this example i'll just pass a string but this can be any variable.

The handle function now looks like

```
function handle(Closure $closure) {
    $closure('Hello World!');
}
```

We now also need to modify the `Closure` itself to take the parameter. We do so by simply adding a parameter to the function. And then we pass that variable to the `echo`.

The function now looks like

```
handle(function($value){
    echo $value;
});
```

Which will echo `Hello World!`

For more information you can check out these links:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php