# why undefined variable in closure laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have two 3 tables : **users,profiles, friend_request**

**$my_profile_id** variable store the value of user's profile ID

```
$my_user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$my_profile_id =   DB::table('profiles')->select('profiles.profile_id', 'profiles.id')->leftjoin('users','users.id' ,'=' ,'profiles.id')->where('users.id',$my_user_id)->pluck('profiles.profile_id')->first();

$friend_accept = DB::table('friend_request')->select('profiles.profile_id','profiles.first_name','interest_request.sent_at','interest_request.interest_id')->leftjoin('profiles', function($join){
$join->on('interest_request.sender_id' , '=','profiles.profile_id');
$join->orOn('interest_request.to_user_id' , '=','profiles.profile_id');
 })->where('to_user_id',$my_profile_id)->orwhere('sender_id',$my_profile_id)->where('interest_status','2')->whereNotIn('profiles.profile_id', function($q)
  {
   $q->select('profiles.profile_id')->from('profiles')->where('profiles.profile_id',$my_profile_id);
   })->groupby('profiles.profile_id')->get();
```

`$my_profile_id` variable is working fine in `where` and `orwhere` clause but when I use in `whereNotIn` sub query clause it create error: Variable is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u create a `closure` but did not  pass parameter into `Closure` so your code is not working

since inside the closure PHP doesn't know the `$my_profile_id` variable you need to have a `use` statement in the closure too

```
$my_user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$my_profile_id =   DB::table('profiles')->select('profiles.profile_id', 'profiles.id')->leftjoin('users','users.id' ,'=' ,'profiles.id')->where('users.id',$my_user_id)->pluck('profiles.profile_id')->first();

$friend_accept = DB::table('friend_request')->select('profiles.profile_id','profiles.first_name','interest_request.sent_at','interest_request.interest_id')->leftjoin('profiles', function($join){
$join->on('interest_request.sender_id' , '=','profiles.profile_id');
$join->orOn('interest_request.to_user_id' , '=','profiles.profile_id');
 })->where('to_user_id',$my_profile_id)
   ->orwhere('sender_id',$my_profile_id)
   ->where('interest_status','2')
   ->whereNotIn('profiles.profile_id', function($q) use ($my_profile_id) {
           $q->select('profiles.profile_id')->from('profiles')
                ->where('profiles.profile_id',$my_profile_id);
   })->groupby('profiles.profile_id')->get();
```

for more info about `Closure` [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348081/what-is-closure-in-laravel)

Comment: Its working, can you please tell me  why my code is not working  without use ($my_profile_id)

Comment: @Entrepreuner ya i updated my answer with clarification

Answer (score 1):

While your code style is a little hard to read, It looks like you are missing a step. However, my preferred code style has already been put down in a reply with probably working code. Don't make live to hard on your self and follow that code style.

Your code:

```
whereNotIn('profiles.profile_id', function($q)
{
```

Posted code:

```
whereNotIn('profiles.profile_id', function($q) use ($my_profile_id) {
```

What happened was you missed a complete instruction on what to use.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not passing `$my_profile_id` variable inside closure...
That`s why it showing `variable is undefined`

```
$my_user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$my_profile_id =   DB::table('profiles')->select('profiles.profile_id', 'profiles.id')->leftjoin('users','users.id' ,'=' ,'profiles.id')->where('users.id',$my_user_id)->pluck('profiles.profile_id')->first();

$friend_accept = DB::table('friend_request')->select('profiles.profile_id','profiles.first_name','interest_request.sent_at','interest_request.interest_id')->leftjoin('profiles', function($join){
$join->on('interest_request.sender_id' , '=','profiles.profile_id');
$join->orOn('interest_request.to_user_id' , '=','profiles.profile_id');
})->where('to_user_id',$my_profile_id)->orwhere('sender_id',$my_profile_id)->where('interest_status','2')->whereNotIn('profiles.profile_id', function($q) use ($my_user_id){ $q->select('profiles.profile_id')->from('profiles')->where('profiles.profile_id',$my_profile_id); })->groupby('profiles.profile_id')->get();
```

Try adding `use ($my_user_id)` after `function($q)`.