# What is `closure` middleware in laravel?

Tags: laravel

When I `route:list` all routes in the system, I find some of the routes have `Closure` middleware.
Although I did only assign `api` and `auth` a middlewares

### api.php

```php
Route::post('api/favorites/{post}', 'api/favorites/{post}')->middleware('auth');
```

### Output

```sh
| Method |         URI          |        Action                 |    Middleware 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| POST   | api/favorites/{post} | \FavoritesController@favorite | api,auth,Closure
```

Comment: closure is `anonymous function` https://stackoverflow.com/a/47348663/7358765

Comment: It's probably the third example of this section: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#controller-middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middlewares can be set as a Closure as well. In case you need a middleware for a single usage only then you don't need to create a dedicated `middleware` for that. Instead, you can just add a Closure middleware in your Controller's `__construct`:

```php
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
   $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
       //your logic
       return $next($request);
   });
}
```